# I don't eat dairy products yet I cant lose weight

Tags: weight-loss

I am a very active person, I started going to the gym in my freshman year in university in 2012, and I gym 6 days aweek. I use weights for squat,I go for 30 minutes running , eliptical and rarely do circuits (my stamina for circuits is very low). I recently started kickboxing which I am enjoying a lot.

However, and given that I am 5'2'' , I find it hard to lose weight around my thighs! I don't eat junk food at all, I gave up dairy recently in all of its means - I rarely drink lattes- and I eat vegetables daily. I spoke to my trainer who told me that because I am short, running will actually make my thighs even more bigger!

to be honest I don't consider myself fat (im 120lb), but I aspire to be much leaner. Perhaps , would eating bread (for breakfast and lunch in the form of sandwiches) be the reason for me not losing any weight in my legs ?

Any recommendations ?

EDIT: I stopped counting my calorie intake a while ago. However, I only burn around 500 calories in the gym, which I think is low given that I love incorporating carbs in my diet!

Comment: I'd dump your trainer.  There's no evidence that being short and running will make your thighs bigger.

Comment: We really need to create a better example question/answer for targeted weight loss...

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the fitness board, Emma. First of all, dairy has nothing to do with your issue, but your calorie intake does. How much your food intake is, and how much you spend as energy expenditure during the whole day is what matters. Regarding your instructor's comment I'd say that no, running doesn't make your legs look fat, but instead stocked and toned. There's no specific exercise to lose weight from legs, but as you are already active, I wouldn't recommend anything, but to keep doing what you are doing. Just make sure your calorie intake doesn't exceed your energy needs.

Comment: What you eat has in fact influence on how your body reacts, metabolism-wise. To be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding your daily life as an equation:

If you eat more than what your body burns daily you will gain weight-

If you eat less, you will lose weight.

How to calculate your daily calorie number? there is numerous website provide calculation for your kcal instake daily using your weight/height/age
Keep it simple
Use quality food -
Replace bad fat with good fat

Answer (score 0):

It's all about calories in vs calories out, I suggest tracking your caloric intake again and make sure you're eating less than what you need by 500 or so calories. Other protocols that have helped me lose weight in the past are intermittent fasting and fasted cardio, hope that helps.